# Как занести значения в базу данных sqlite3 через aiogram3

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста, как мне занести данные в базу данных через aiogram3

**выводит эту ошибку** -     cur.execute("SELECT name FROM accounts")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: accounts

там вроде в файле main надо как то подключать, я по роликам смотрел на ютубе, но там был aiogram 2 и тот способ мне не подошел.
Там в ролике импортировали из aiogram.utils  executor, и еще там в start_polling указывали ключ (вроде ключ,я не знаю точно как называется:( ) on_startup= <функция с db>.
Помогите пожалуйста как в aiogram 3 реализовать эту операцию

**main**

```
from aiogram import Bot,Dispatcher
from handlers import database as db
token ="токен"

from handlers import bot_messages,user_commands,account

async def on_startup():
    await db.db_start()
    print("Бот запущен")



async def main():
    dp = Dispatcher()
    bot = Bot(token=token, parse_mode='html')
    dp.include_routers(
        user_commands.router,
        account.router,
        bot_messages.router
        )
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**database**

```
import sqlite3 as sq

db=sq.connect("br_main")
cur=db.cursor()

async def db_start():
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST accounts("
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                "name TEXT."
                "description TEXT,"
                "reg INT )""")
    db.commit()
```

**account**

```
from aiogram import  Router,F,Bot
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from BeatsRate.utils.states import Form
from BeatsRate.keyboards_main.reply import main
import sqlite3 as sq
from BeatsRate.keyboards_main.builder import profile
from BeatsRate.keyboards_main.reply import rmk

router=Router()

@router.message(Command(commands=["profile","pr"]))
async def fill_profile(message:Message,state:FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Form.nickname)#set_state-создание нового стейта
    await message.answer(
        "Введите свой никнейм или можете оставить свой текущий username в телеграме, нажав на кнопку",
        reply_markup=profile(message.from_user.username)
    )


#Обновляет значение
@router.message(Form.nickname)
async def form_name(message:Message,state:FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(nickname=message.text)
    db = sq.connect("br_main")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM accounts")
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO accounts VALUES('{message.text}')")
    db.commit()
    await state.set_state(Form.description)
    await message.answer("Описание",reply_markup=rmk)
```

Comment: Код создания таблицы нерабочий.

Comment: ну S  я добавил к EXIST и db приписал , ниче не поменялось, как было no such table accounts так оно и осталось

Comment: Покажите изменённый код. Только не пишите в комментариях, редактируйте вопрос.